# Подсчитать количество записей по дереву подкатегорий

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть 2 таблицы:

1 - таблица категорий, и связей (cat2 и cat3 подчиняется cat1)

```
prod_category
id|name|parent_category|
1 |cat1|       0       |
2 |cat2|       1       |
3 |cat3|       1       |
4 |cat4|       3       |
5 |cat5|       3       |
6 |cat6|       0       |
7 |cat7|       6       |
8 |cat8|       0       |
9 |cat9|       8       |
10|cat10|      9       |
```

2 - таблица продуктов и их категории

```
products
id| name|category_id|
1 |prod1|     0     |
2 |prod2|     1     |
3 |prod3|     2     |
4 |prod4|     3     |
5 |prod5|     4     |
6 |prod6|     5     |
7 |prod7|     6     |
8 |prod8|     7     |
9 |prdo9|     8     |
10|prod10|    9     |
```

Я делаю sql цикл родительских категорий:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM prod_category WHERE parent_category='0'");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

}
```

Далее мне нужно просчитать есть закреплена ли эта категория в продуктах (есть ли в ней продукты).
Если нет, тогда взять категорию которая подчиняется (дочерняя) и посчитать есть ли в ней продукты, и до кона связей. Если продукты в какой либо категории (дочерней либо же в самой родительской) есть, тогда выводим `$row['name']`, если нет, тогда не выводим.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(products.*,prod_category.*) FROM prod_category, products WHERE products.id= prod_category.parent_category

Comment: @Юрий ошибку синтаксиса бьет. Можете в ответ развернуть?

Comment: сколько уровней вложенности категорий?

Comment: как минимум основную категорию надо считать в запросе, джойном. с родительскими уже будут варианты

Comment: @Ипатьев неизвестно, может и 10 и 100

Comment: это точно про *вложенность*?

Comment: @Ипатьев Сколько может быть уровней иерархии?

Comment: да, сколько уровней иерархии

Comment: @Ипатьев значит верно, и 10 и 100 может быть

Comment: Если интересно, можете погуглить в сторону `Nested Sets`

Comment: люблю людей с богатой фантазией. ну тогда select category_id from products вернет тебе все категории в которых есть товары. а дальше уже своим циклом

Comment: @Ипатьев не совсем понял Вас, можете на примере показать?

Comment: уточняем задачу. тебе надо вывести только родительские категории, в которых есть товары?

Comment: @Ипатьев выводим только родительские категории либо в которых есть товары, либо в которых есть дочерние категории а в них есть товары.

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете использовать следующий код:

```
<?php
// get categoriies into array >>>
$sth = $pdo->prepare("select * from prod_category");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$categories = [];
foreach ($result as $c) {
    $categories[$c['id']] = $c;
};
// <<< get categoriies into array

// recursive function get product main category
function get_main_category($cat) {
    global $categories;
    
    return $categories[$cat]['parent_category'] == 0 
        ? $categories[$cat]['name']
        : get_main_category($categories[$cat]['parent_category']);
}

$sth = $pdo->prepare("select * from products");
$sth->execute();

$result = [];
while ($prod = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $prod['main_category'] = get_main_category($prod['category_id']);
    if (isset($res[$prod['main_category']])) $res[$prod['main_category']]++;
    else $res[$prod['main_category']] = 1;
}

print_r($res);
```

Здесь можно протестировать [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=338bd1d82d07ccf7dc64b87aae31f9bc&sqlses=449d56657cdda220f95171245078fe4d&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Господа минусатры, буду рад получить коструктивную критику ответа, вместо анонимного минусаторства